# Same tag, different properties (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, html-lists

is it possible for one tag to have different properties? For example, I have this:

```
<li><a href="/#"><img src="Images/facebook.png" alt="FaceBook" style="width:25px;height:25px;"></a></li>
<li><a href="/#"><img src="Images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" style="width:25px;height:25px;"></a></li>
<li><a href="/#"><img src="Images/youtube.png" alt="YouTube" style="width:25px;height:25px;"></a></li>
```

And this:

```
<li><a href="/#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/#">Roster</a></li>
<li><a href="/#">Store</a></li>
<li><a href="/#">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="/#">Our Sponsor</a></li>
<li><a href="/#">About</a></li>
```

But I want to have different properties for the 'li' tag. This:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

was used for the 2nd lot of listed items, and want different properties for the 1st lot, as I don't want the 'margin-left' that high on the icons. Thanks guys, please tell me if you need me to explain it more or give you more information.

Comment: Yes, but you should classes to differentiate between the two lists. That's what they are for,

Comment: @Paulie_D — There's no such thing. HTML has classes, CSS has class  selectors.

Comment: How would I do that, @Paulie_D ?

Comment: There are lots of different ways to do this. They all boil down to "Write a more specific selector". http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/getting-to-know-css/

Comment: easiest way, is to put two different classes on the `<ul>` elements or whatever you have wrapping those `li`s.. then select them with css like so: `.class1 li` and `.class2 li`

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, sorry, I mean classes **in** the CSS..just trying to keep it simple. Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

`<li><a href="/#"><img src="Images/facebook.png" alt="FaceBook" style="width:25px;height:25px;"></a></li>
<li><a href="/#"><img src="Images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" style="width:25px;height:25px;"></a></li>
<li><a href="/#"><img src="Images/youtube.png" alt="YouTube" style="width:25px;height:25px;"></a></li>`

to

```
<li class="icons"><a href="/#"><img src="Images/facebook.png" alt="FaceBook" style="width:25px;height:25px;"></a></li>
<li class="icons"><a href="/#"><img src="Images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" style="width:25px;height:25px;"></a></li>
<li class="icons"><a href="/#"><img src="Images/youtube.png" alt="YouTube" style="width:25px;height:25px;"></a></li>
```

and then duplicated the li class and changed the 'margin-left'. Thanks guys

Comment: It works, but it's poor programming practice. You want to write as least amount of code as possible so that it's easier to manage and faster to run... what you should do instead is wrap each set of `li` elements inside something like a `ul` and give each `ul` a unique class. Then, write some css for the `li` element in general that is common for all li elements. Then, write two selectors for each `some_ul_class li` --this will select all the `li` elements inside that `ul`. That's where you want to put your unique properies

Answer (score -1):

Add li tag inside a ul tag..

```html
<ul class="class1">
    <li><a href="/#"><img src="Images/facebook.png" alt="FaceBook" style="width:25px;height:25px;"></a></li>
    <li><a href="/#"><img src="Images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" style="width:25px;height:25px;"></a></li>
    <li><a href="/#"><img src="Images/youtube.png" alt="YouTube" style="width:25px;height:25px;"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Add css based on this span tag...

```css
.class1 li {
list-style: none;
float: left;
margin-left: 100px;
padding-top: 25px;
font-family: Open Sans;
position: relative;
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}`
```

Comment: Don't put `li` elements inside of a span tag, that's not what span is for!